# What do I do to get the fish hook in the painting?

Tags: ib

I'm at the part where you're switching between Ib and Garry. I got the umbrella from the gassy room, and now I'm supposed to put it on the fish hook in the painting. But, there is no fish hook in it. I even switched back to Ib and there was no fisherman in the painting titled 'The Fisherman'. What do I do to get the fish hook in the painting?